# Running code at boot?

Tags: ios, boot, springboard

I am creating a rather ambitious project for the iOS and I need to run some code during the boot stage, before the springboard actually launches. I understand that this can harm the device, but it is extremely crucial. I noticed while jailbreaking an iPad Mini with evasi0n that the jailbreak actually runs code at boot (it actually copies some files and displays an image). Any idea on how I can do it?

P.S. I already checked, no source code for evasi0n lying around :(

Comment: So, is this for jailbroken devices?

Comment: Of course :) I also thought about replacing the Springboard binary with my own, then putting it back and reboot/respring but it seems just stupid...

Comment: @NickAlieropoulos It kinda is... See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Launch Daemon and install it. You should go through the following procedure:

1. Create your program (a normal executable with `main()` etc.) and put it into one of the standard executable paths. I suggest you use `/usr/libexec/` for this purpose.
2. Create a property list in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` of which the name is an arbitrary bundle ID (e. g. `com.mycompany.NastyLaunchDaemon.plist`), and its contents are the following:

---

```
<plist>
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <!-- this needs to match the file name without the .plist extension! -->
    <string>com.mycompany.NastyLaunchDaemon</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/libexec/mynastylaunchd</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true />
</dict>
</plist>
```

After you reboot your device, the program will run.

Comment: Thanks that's great! And when it hits return 0; it will launch the SpringBoard normally?

Comment: @NickAliferopoulos Huh, what?

Comment: It will execute my binary at boot, right? And when it is executed, it will boot normally and launch springboard... Or not?

Comment: @NickAliferopoulos Of course it will, launch daemons don't remove functionality, only add.

Comment: That's nice! Thanks for your help! :)